# Ext JS 4.2.1 + Sencha CMD - ItemSelector Buttons CSS not loaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I generated an Ext JS 4.2.1.883 application with the sencha CMD 3.1.2.342 using nthe neptune theme...
I've got an `ItemSelector` Control in my View with the Buttons `'add'` and `'remove'`..

I executed a `sencha ant cleaen` and `sencha app build` still my Buttons of the ItemsControl are without any Icon. It seems that my generated `Appname-all.css` does not include the CSS of the `ItemSelector.css` file in my `ext\src\ux` folder where e.g a style would be defined for the css class .x-form-itemselector-add. In the `Appname-all.scss` file i found a variable `$include-ext-ux-form-itemselector` which is set to true. I dont know how i can fix this.. 
I already tried to write `Ext.require('Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector');` and `Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', './ext/src/ux');` in my application.js file.

I dont know how to proceed - please help!

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the [multiselect](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html) example in the Ext JS docs, inspecting the buttons in the middle (e.g. "x-form-itemselector-add") clearly show the CSS is not part of the theme - it's a completely separate CSS file.

In fact, just looking at the HTML source code shows the [CSS file](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/ux/css/ItemSelector.css).

You'll need to add that CSS to your theme manually and then recompile. The Sencha UX JS and CSS files don't have auto-inclusion flags via Cmd.

Comment: That or just manually include the separate CSS file - but it's better practice to port it into your own theme.